# How can I disable registry editing (with RegEdit) by a guest account?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, user-accounts, regedit

How do I disable registry editing (with RegEdit) by a guest account in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log on as Administrator on you pc. Go to Start > Run > gpedit.msc

- Group Policy Editor. Then navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > System.
- Prevent access to registry editing tools, select either Disabled or Not Configured.
- Now close the Group Policy Editor and restart your PC.

Comment: But remember that the user can just bring his own tools which don't check for this.